# SAS Visual Analytics graph resolution

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

Good morning lads,

I have a very important question regarding the resolution in SAS Visual Analytics and I'm kinda in a hurry. I have a lot of graphs inside my dashboard but when I open the same graphs in LabView or Excel I see a much more detailed graph. I think SAS VA cannot handle the same resolution. Does this have something to do with resolution actually? Can I adjust it to make my graph more detailed in SAS VA or is this something SAS has made by default? I saw something that was named 'fixed bin count' and I could only put this to a maximum of 500. Is this 500 the resolution?

Comment: Can you show the images made with VA and Excel to demonstrate the resolution difference ?

Comment: @Richard I can show you in some private chat. You have any platform?